# Recover long lost shares held by brokerage that got acquired

Tags: investing, shares, brokerage

I am a UK citizen and had a brokerage account with suretrade.com in 2001, with a number of positions in NASDAQ traded companies which today would be worth a few thousand USD for the companies still trading.

I changed address around then, did not update with the brokerage and for various reasons never successfully got around to recovering my investments. In the meantime, suretrade was acquired in 2001 by Fleet Boston's Quick & Reilly, which in turn merged with Bank of America in 2004.

Is there any way I can recover these investments or has too much time passed? If I can recover them, what are the options to achieve this?

The only paperwork I have is a page from a statement dated 31/3/2001; no contract, etc.

Comment: This brokerage never failed, so this doesn't seem like a case for SIPC.  What have you learned from Bank of America's customer service?

Comment: @user662852 I have not been able to find a Bank of America contact number that allows me to connect to a human without having a valid account number and/or social-security number!

Comment: an update on this; managed to get through to someone - ended up being a desk at Merrill Lynch Wealth Management who are a part of BoA. While very helpful and well-informed, they struggled to find any reference to my account. We speculated that at the point of acquisition/merger there was possibly a request to clients to either move over their account, transfer to another broker or liquidate positions and close account. However since this was more than ten years ago, there was no paper trail...and possibly it was sent to lost property.

Comment: I checked with Rhode Island lost property, where suretrade was registered prior to acquisition, but nothing comes up in my name. Likewise for Florida (where I believe Quick & Reilly were incorporated?), and Massachusetts (First Boston)...

Comment: Did you ever recover your property?

Comment: no. I hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

Your trading account login and password might have been deleted, but the contract you signed as a customer is binding for the succeeding firms.

For example, a very well known broker TD-Direct was acquired recently and renamed to Internaxx. This did not affect client accounts, and even opened positions.

So I would suggest you to find your contract and demand to sort this thing out. If you are unlucky, the contract might have contained that positions get closed out automatically after a certain period of time.

If things don't go well, turn to the financial regulator; in the USA it should be the SEC.

Comment: All I have is a page from a statement that I kept - so that in the future I might do the legwork to figure out how to recover the positions. Didn't have my policy of scan everything important and store on a dropbox-like setup! :)